# How to merge 5 different type of linq queries into one based on a column

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, sqlite, linq-to-sql

I am really confused on a report I need. As of today, most of my reports were simple, so I was able to do them myself easily. But being a newbie in sql/dlinq, I cannot find my way through the following:

```
var closingStock =
    (from p in session.Query<Product>()
    select new
    {
        p.Id,
        p.Name,
        p.Batch,
        p.Rate,
        ClosingStock = p.Quantity - p.AllocatedQuantity,
        p.DivisionId
    }).ToList();

var distributedQuantityAfterPeriod =
    (from i in session.Query<OutwardInvoiceItem>()
    where i.ParentInvoice.Date > ToDate 
    select new
    {
        Id = i.Product.Id,
        DistributedAfter = i.Quantity
    }).ToList();

var distributedQuantityInPeriod =
    (from i in session.Query<OutwardInvoiceItem>()
    where i.ParentInvoice.Date >= FromDate && i.ParentInvoice.Date <= ToDate
    select new
    {
        Id = i.Product.Id,
        Distributed = i.Quantity
    }).ToList();

var receivedQuantityAfterPeriod =
    (from i in session.Query<InwardInvoiceItem>()
    where i.ParentInvoice.Date > ToDate
    select new
    {
        Id = i.Product.Id,
        ReceivedAfter = i.Quantity
    }).ToList();

var receivedQuantityInPeriod =
    (from i in session.Query<InwardInvoiceItem>()
    where i.ParentInvoice.Date >= FromDate && i.ParentInvoice.Date <= ToDate
    select new
    {
        Id = i.Product.Id,
        Received = i.Quantity
    }).ToList();
```

As you can see, I am trying to build a inventory movement report for a specific date. I have the following problems:
1. How can I reduce the five queries? Is it possible?
2. How can I merge the data provided by these queries into one table which is grouped on the product id and summed on the quantity related columns? As of now, I am using for loops which are really slow.

What I am using:
C# 4, nHibernate, Sqlite

Any help will be very highly appreciated.

Regards,
Yogesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. to reduce roundtrips use `.Future()` instead of `.List()`
2. let all queries return

   ```
   group i by i.Id into g
   select new
   {
       Id = g.Key,
       Quantity = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity)
   }).Future();
   ```

and do

```
var alltogether = groupedDistributedQuantityAfterPeriod
    .Concat(groupedDistributedQuantityInPeriod)
    .Concate(...);

from g in alltogether
group g by g.key into all
select new
{
    Id = all.Key,
    Quantity = all.Sum(x => x.Quantity)
};
```

Update:

you can reduce the number of queries with

```
from i in session.Query<OutwardInvoiceItem>()
where (i.ParentInvoice.Date > ToDate) || (i.ParentInvoice.Date >= FromDate && i.ParentInvoice.Date <= ToDate)
select ...

from i in session.Query<InwardInvoiceItem>()
where (i.ParentInvoice.Date > ToDate) || (i.ParentInvoice.Date >= FromDate && i.ParentInvoice.Date <= ToDate)
select ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already figured out the way to merge all tables using linq. But using Future with Concat is indeed giving me faster results. If there is no answer about reducing the number of queries, I will select your answer.